# Dragging IE HTM shortcut to Chrome shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, drag-and-drop

Whenever I drag a shortcut to Chrome...

[image: 42]

...a page opens up containing this:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Whenever I try this with IE, StackOverflow actually opens up. And, no, I don't want to set my default browser as Chrome (yet) as others use this computer, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Chrome won't read `.url` files when you pass this as a parameter.
Strangely enough, it works if you drag and drop the `.url` file in an open instance of Chrome.

Additional discussion at :

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5d81b8d36ccd3684&hl=en